# How to read a file and write in 2 different files in java

Tags: java, file

I have a large file comprising of question and answers. I want to put questions in one file and answer on other file.The only way to identify whether the question ends/answer begins is a '?'. and the answer ends in a ''. Kindly help...

Note: the answer begins at the same line question ends..however the next question begins on a different line.

Comment: care to show us the actual file and expected output?

Comment: Parse the file , Split by `newline` first , this way you get all question answer pairs in an `String[]`  . Next split each element of Array with `?` , this way you get individual questions and answers. Iterate through all the `String[]` and write it to the files accordingly.

Comment: Answer can be more than one line ?

Comment: Show us what have you tried? Post some code. Give examples of input file.

Answer (score 0):

- Open the Source file in read mode Read each line one by one.
- Split each lines data by "?" by which you are identified that your
  question is ended.
- Now your can write Question in one file and Answer in other file.
- Repeat it until you reach end of file

Answer (score 0):

Change the respective file names and run the below code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File rFile = new File("QuestAndAnsFile.txt");
        BufferedReader in = null;
        BufferedWriter questFileWriter = null;
        BufferedWriter ansFileWriter = null;
        try
        {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(rFile));

            questFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("questions.txt"));
            ansFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("answers.txt"));

            while (in.ready()) 
            {
              String s = in.readLine();
              if(s.endsWith("?"))
              {
                  questFileWriter.write(s+"\n");
              }
              else
              {
                  ansFileWriter.write(s+"\n");
              }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try{
                if(in != null){  in.close(); }
                if(questFileWriter != null) { questFileWriter.close();}
                if(ansFileWriter != null) { ansFileWriter.close();}
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }
}
```

Updated:

```
while (in.ready()) 
{
   String s = in.readLine();
   String[] qs = s.split("\\?");
   if(qs.length == 2)
   {
      //Assume that all line should contains question and ans
      questFileWriter.write(qs[0]+"\n");
      ansFileWriter.write(qs[1]+"\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a point here. `Note: the answer begins at the same line question ends..however the next question begins on a different line.`

Comment: Yes, you must split it by "?" first and the array need to use 0 for question and 1 for answer